# Where is "coffee" coming from in the arrow function within the map function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone please tell me where `coffee` is coming from in the arrow function within the map function?

```js
constructor(handlers, ingredientsToBeAdded) {
    const resultHandler = (coffee) => {
        // console.log('Final');
        console.log(`Result coffee: ${Object.keys(coffee).filter((item) => item !== 'ingredientsToBeAdded').join(', ')}`);
    };

    this.handlers = [...Object.values(handlers), resultHandler]
        .map((handler, index) => {
            return (coffee) => {
                console.log('ddddddddddd', coffee)
                handler(coffee, this.handlers[index + 1]);
            }
        });

    this.coffeeCup = {
        ingredientsToBeAdded,
    };

    console.log('Initial handlers are set');
    console.log(this.handlers);
}
```

full code

```
/**
 * Class presenting a request to create a coffee
 */
class CoffeeMachine {
    /**
     * Create concrete element
     * @param {Array} handlers - handlers set to pass the request through
     */
    constructor(handlers, ingredientsToBeAdded) {
        const resultHandler = (coffee) => {
            // console.log('Final');
            console.log(`Result coffee: ${Object.keys(coffee).filter((item) => item !== 'ingredientsToBeAdded').join(', ')}`);
        };
        this.handlers = [...Object.values(handlers), resultHandler].map((handler, index) => {

            return (coffee) => {
                console.log('ddddddddddd',coffee)
                handler(coffee, this.handlers[index + 1]);
            }


        });
        this.coffeeCup = {
            ingredientsToBeAdded,
        };

        console.log('Initial handlers are set');
        console.log(this.handlers);
    }

    /**
     * Set new ingredients to be added to coffee
     * @param { Array } ingredients - ingredients to be added
     * @return { self } this - instance of itself
     */
    setNewIngredients(ingredientsToBeAdded) {
        this.coffeeCup = {
            ingredientsToBeAdded,
        };
        // console.log(`Cup is replaced with a new ingredients: ${ingredientsToBeAdded.join(', ')}`);

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Process coffee
     * @return { String } coffee - dedicated coffee description according to the corresponding handlers passed
     */
    processCoffee() {
        this.handlers[0](this.coffeeCup);
    }
}

// ============================================================
// USAGE
// ============================================================

// Set of handlers to process a coffee cup
const coffeeHandlers = {
    addCoffee: (coffee, next) => {
        coffee.espresso = true;
        // console.log('Espresso is added');
        next(coffee);
    },
    addMilk: (coffee, next) => {
        if (coffee.ingredientsToBeAdded.includes('milk')) {
            coffee.withMilk = true;
            // console.log('Milk is added');
        }

        next(coffee);
    },
    addSugar: (coffee, next) => {
        if (coffee.ingredientsToBeAdded.includes('sugar')) {
            coffee.withSugar = true;
            // console.log('Sugar is added');
        }

        next(coffee);
    },
    addCinnamon: (coffee, next) => {
        if (coffee.ingredientsToBeAdded.includes('cinnamon')) {
            coffee.withCinnamon = true;
            // console.log('Cinnamon is added');
        }

        next(coffee);
    },
};

// Instantiate a concrete coffee machine (1)
const coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(coffeeHandlers, ['sugar', 'milk', 'cinnamon']);
// Process coffee for an initial ingredients set ^^^ (2)
coffeeMachine
    .processCoffee();

// // Set new ingredients and process coffee with them (3)
// coffeeMachine
//     .setNewIngredients(['sugar'])
//     .processCoffee();
//
// // Set another new ingredients and process coffee with them (4)
// coffeeMachine
//     .setNewIngredients(['milk', 'cinnamon'])
//     .processCoffee();

// RESULTS
// (1)
// "Initial handlers are set"

// (2)
// "Espresso is added"
// "Milk is added"
// "Sugar is added"
// "Cinnamon is added"
// "Result coffee description: espresso, withMilk, withSugar, withCinnamon"

// (3)
// "Cup is replaced with a new ingredients: sugar"
// "Espresso is added"
// "Sugar is added"
// "Result coffee description: espresso, withSugar"

// (4)
// "Cup is replaced with a new ingredients: milk, cinnamon"
// "Espresso is added"
// "Milk is added"
// "Cinnamon is added"
// "Result coffee description: espresso, withMilk, withCinnamon"
```

Comment: arrow functions take arguments, just like non-arrow functions. If you just want to understand how the arguments work, take your code, rewrite every `(...) => { ... }` to `function(...) { ... }` until you're confortable with the arrow syntax. (but don't _save_ that code, because arrow functions behave differently from regular functions and if used correctly they are _not_ interchangeable in the slightest)

Comment: im sorry but if you take a look at the full gist i dont declare the variable coffee and its aviable to pass in the handler function but where is this coffee coming from
https://gist.github.com/dcd-api/b11aa1473f30931cd55bdbf56cfc960e

Comment: I will not be reading your gist: if there's something in the gist that is important to your question, but not in your post, please [put all the details in your post](/help/how-to-ask), folks should _not_ need to go off-site to get all the information they need to help you. Right now, given what's in your post, `coffee` is an just a function argument, and [given how the Array.prototype.map function works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it should be clear how it's getting instantiated.

Comment: "*i dont declare the variable coffee*" - yes you do. It's a function parameter. Just the same as `handlers`, `ingredientsToBeAdded`, `handler`, and `index`.

Comment: As a side note it's worth pointing out that while arrow functions _accept_ arguments they don't support the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#description) like function declarations.